# nVidia on Ubuntu 14.04 black login screen (not freeze)

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, lightdm, nvidia-optimus

Recently I installed STEAM on my Lenovo IdeaPad Y510p (core i7 + nVidia 755m) laptop running Ubuntu 14.04. I want to use nVidia for sessions when I play games and Intel for everything else. Therefore I installed nVidia drivers (tried several times, binnary from nVidia site and from Ubuntu repo but never from PPA).

**Lightdm never manage to display login screen** when nVidia is selected (using primus or nVidia prime indicator applet). Screen is black, no mouse arrow and system does not freeze, I can hear drum startup sound and I can switch to console by pressing ctrl+alt+f1 and logon successfully (I use this to switch back to intel).

I checked for brightness setup, changed them both to max and it didn't help (it affect brightness in terminal). Connecting external TV on HDMI also didnt help (same picture on both diplays: when works using intel and when it does not work using nvidia). in BIOS I have no options related to GPUs...

I'm under impression that **issue is not with driver** - but on lightdm side or x side - like they cannot pick the right connector to send picture to display...
Both next commands works, but I can only see black display when switching to nvidia

```
sudo prime-switch nvidia
sudo prime-switch intel
```

Any help is appreciated?
I already tried everything else from web but it dint helped My laptop never freezes and because of that I think the issue is not the same...

Comment: did you ever figure out a slick solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know from bitter experience that at any given time there are several nvidia drivers available and each one has its own pros and cons.  I learned that after I "upgraded" to a later version only to spend hours putting it back the way I had it the first time.

I admit I'm not clear about your wishing to switch it off.  I think what you need is the [nvidia control panel](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1673941&p=10389746#post10389746) so you can turn it on and off on the fly.

I used to have that on one of my computers.  To get it I would advise you to go into the "[Synaptic Package Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto)" and there type, "nvidia control".  You will get several results most of which I suspect you'll be interested in.

PS:  If you don't already have the "Synaptic Package Manager" installed you can install it from the the Ubuntu Software Center"

Comment: I have nvidia control panel (nvidia-setting) installed, but I can reach it only while running intel and in that case only option to switch to nvidia (performance) is available (this makes sense since only intel is active and nvidia is disabled). It behaves exactly the same as using prime-switch in terminal or prime indicator applet...

Comment: I am pretty sure that what I was using had a lot more settings than switching to the other device, so maybe we aren't talking about the same thing.  It should look something like this:

http://img.hexus.net/v2/articles/linux-ati-nvidia/nvidia-settings-001.png

Comment: no, man. All this nvidia settings appear when you run x using nvidia. When i try that i see black screen, so maybe all nvidia settings is there, hidden behind all of that pitch black.